# How to fetch data from db using mysql-crud NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, orm, crud, node-mysql

I have been developing in node for quite sometime and began to get frustrated with writing just abou the same queries for different projects. I came of a CodeIgnitor/Laravel Background where ORM rules the day and I was pissed that express, node-mysql or nodejs kind of has nothing to do with databases per se. I searched this on NPM and against all ORM modules that i found, i liked  [mysql-crud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-crud) . The documentation seems easy enough but am having a little problem returning the data. here is how I am doing it:

```
//pool return a connection pool from the Database connection file

var CRUD = require('mysql-crud');
var users_crud = CRUD(pool, 'users');

function getUsers(callback){
    user-crud.load({}, callback, {'offset' : 10});
}

module.exports = {getUsers}
```

if I run the code as this

```
app.get('/users', (req, res)=>{
    getUsers(response=>{
        res.json(response)
    })
})
```

Hitting this endpoint in Postman return null results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was in the same boat as you are now, when I transitioned toward node from laravel. Try Sequelize library its the best ORM library I found. https://sequelize.org/master/

Comment: Thank you @RohitDalal, I will take a look